# AJAXControlToolKit Partial postback not working

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I thought including ajax control toolkit is a simple thing, but for some odd reason it's not working. It always triggers a full postback from a button inside UpdatePanel.

I am using VS 2015 / asp.net 4.6.1 / Class Library output type. ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll v18.1.1 is added via Nuget. I created a very basic web form page with only an update panel and a label outside of it. Clicking on a button inside update panel always causes a full post, updating the label outside along with it.

Oddly enough, I created a blank Web Site project with the same page and code behind, and it works fine as expected there.

I use browser debugging tool to observe the network output. The site that works appears to have 1 reference to WebResource.axd and 2 references to ScriptResource.axd. Versus the site that doesn't work having only 1 reference to Scriptresource.axd and none to WebResource.axd.

Is there something I missed? Any further techniques I can use to troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One full day of trouble shooting. This setting in web.config prevents ajax control toolkit from performing partial page load.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax